# MySql question with multi-field primary keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table with a primary key which is built from three columns. In an other table I would like to reference to them as one single column foreign key. How can this be resolved? Maybe an id alias? Or how can this be resolved?

Comment: Why don't you have an auto-increment id column in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to do this, just use all three as a foreign key. You could introduce an additional unique-values column on the original, and reference that, but it isn't a great approach.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there is a problem in my concept with this approach, but thanks for answering.